# Appending to an R List one by one

Tags: r

Let's say I have data like:

```
> data[295:300,]
          Date sulfate nitrate ID
295 2003-10-22      NA      NA  1
296 2003-10-23      NA      NA  1
297 2003-10-24    3.47   0.363  1
298 2003-10-25      NA      NA  1
299 2003-10-26      NA      NA  1
300 2003-10-27      NA      NA  1
```

Now I would like to add all the `nitrate` values into a new list/vector. I'm using the following code:

```
i <- 1
my_list <- c()

for(val in data)
{
    my_list[i] <- val
    i <- i + 1
}
```

But this is what happens:

```
Warning message:
In x[i] <- val :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> i
[1] 2
> x
[1] NA
```

Where am I going wrong? The data is part of a Coursera R Programming coursework. I can assure you that this is not an assignment/quiz. I have been trying to understand what is the best way append elements into a list with a loop? I have not proceeded to the `lapply` or `sapply` part of the coursework, so thinking about workarounds.

Thanks in advance.

If it's a duplicate question, please direct me to it.

Comment: "my_list" is not really a good name to call it - it's a **vector** and not a **list**. In R there's a big difference.

Comment: Don't append if you can help it. construct a vector of the length you want before the loop and fill it in: `my_list <- numeric(length(data))`. Then your existing cod  should work.

Comment: If you change `for(val in data)` to `for(val in data$nitrate)` you should get what you want.

Comment: Your `for` loop is iterating over the `data.frame` one column at a time: `for (val in data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)) { str(val) }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we mention in the comments, you are not looping over the rows of your data frame, but the columns (also sometimes variables). Hence, loop over `data$nitrate`.

```
i <- 1
my_list <- c()

for(val in data$nitrate)
{
    my_list[i] <- val
    i <- i + 1
}
```

Now, instead of looping over your values, a better way is to use that you want the new vector and the old data to have the same index, so loop over the index `i`. How do you tell R how many indexes there are? Here you have several choices again: `1:nrow(data)`, `1:length(data$nitrate)` and several other ways. Below I have given you a few examples of how to extract from the data frame.

```
my_vector <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    my_vector[i] <- data$nitrate[i]    ## Version 1 of extracting from data.frame
    my_vector[i] <- data[i,"nitrate"]  ## Version 2: [row,column name]
    my_vector[i] <- data[i,3]          ## Version 3: [row,column number]
}
```

---

My suggestion: Rather than calling the collection a list, call it a vector, since that is what it is. Vectors and lists behave a little differently in R.

---

Of course, in reality you don't want to get the data out one by one. A much more efficient way of getting your data out is

```
my_vector2 <- data$nitrate
```

Comment: Hey @Therkel, thanks for the help. This really helped. I realized that I could also call with data[['nitrate']]. Revisited the subsetting techiques, and now I can do it okay.

Also, thanks for the advice on the naming conventions.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, `data[['nitrate']]` is a useful method also and is often used for lists. Don't hesitate to ask more of this kind of well-formulated question.